# Translation of 「そんなことない」

Tags: translation, expressions, idioms

What is a correct translation for 「そんなことない」 and when can it be used?

I understand the "this is wrong"/"this is not correct" general sense but is this considered either as harsh or a gentle way of showing disagreement?

Also a direct translation would be "there is no such thing". Can this expression be applied to a person?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is relatively gentle, and a good way of allaying fears or dispelling misconceptions.

> お邪魔みたいですので、これで失礼しますね… It seems like I'm interrupting you, so I'll see myself out...
>   そんなこと（は）ないですよ Not at all! / Don't be silly! / No such thing!
>
> かなり怖い人だそうですけど… I heard he's quite a scary person...
>   そんなことない Not at all.

If by your last question you mean can the "thing" be a person, I would say no. When you start making the "thing" a literal object instead of a fact, そんなものはない (there is no such thing [here]) fits better, and for people, そんな人はいない (there is no such person [here]).

Comment: This is what I wanted to figure out. Thanks!